# find the least number in loop and verify if it is equal to certain integer value in groovy

Tags: loops, groovy

I am relatively new with groovy, so i am not sure if i am doing this right

I am running my query in a loop to find the least value , if that least value is equal to say 12 , then print it

```
 connection.eachRow(query) {

    def errorstate = false
    if (y < x && y !=0)
    {
    errorstate = true
    x = y  ---> if y is less than x then set x = value of y
    }
  /* if y is greater then  the value of x will not change */
if (x == 12) 
    printf ("%-30s\t%-20s\t\n" , name,y)

    }
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to run above script (part of my original script) but it doesnt seem to be working correctly. It is running though but no output even if i reduce my end value for x=2/3 ? Not sure if the script is correct or not !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
connection.eachRow(query) {

    def errorstate = false
    if (y != 0)
    {
        errorstate = y < x
        x = Math.min(x, y)
    }

}

/* if y is greater then  the value of x will not change */
if (x == 12) 
    printf "%-30s\t%-20s\t\n" , name, y
```

This assumes that `eachRow` will call the closure it's given on each row before returning. I don't know if that's the case because you did not post which library you're using to do this.

It could well be that `eachRow` will run the closure in a separate thread, returning immediately before running any loop. Check the documentation of `eachRow` to see if that's the case.

Comment: What if i use value 0 for y as well, as the query returns few values with 0 (which means a process was run in less than an hour) i tried with if ( y >= 0 ) but it still returned values with 12 , even though there were 0s .

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. I need the context of what you're trying to achieve to be able to help. Perhaps ask a new question with more details on what you are doing, what exactly is not working, what you've tried so far...

Comment: so i get the values 0,1,2,3,4 (these are in hours for 5 systems as an example) the process has been running ,if it returns 0 means it ran just few mins back or less than an hour, if it is 1, the process ran an hour back. If the process ran in the last hour or so for all the systems then do nothing, if did not run for more than or equal to 12 hours(in any system) then email !! Does this make sense?

Comment: Is this your homework? It's a simple problem. What you really want is to find  if any process ran for the last time 12 hours or more ago. The first part of your sentence seems irrelevant. so the code just needs to find if any number is 12 or more: `def anyLateProcess = connection.rows(query).any { row -> row >= 12 }; if (anyLateProcess) email()`